# How to make a simple API python

Tags: python, api, http, flask, client-server

I have a computer, and I want to interact with another computers via an API.

I am the server, and the other is my client.

The client has the following file client.py on its computer

```
import numpy as np
import random as rd
import time

def update(server_value):
    time.sleep(3*rd.random())
    return server_value + np.random.normal(0,1)
```

On the server side, what I want to do is:

```
server_value = 10  #initialize server value
rounds = 20

for round in range(rounds):
    (send server value to both clients)  # I don't know how to do this in Python
    (execute update on both clients)  # Locally, the clients perform the update function on the new data
    (send the return value to the server)
    server_value = (value_client1+value_client2)*0.5 # We aggregate the values of all clients.
```

The expected result here is that server_value is unchanged at the end of the loop.

I think what I need is to create an API hosted by every of the clients. Then, in the for loop over the previous code, I want to send data using POST method, and then each clients apply the update function to the given data. Then, the server update server_value with the value of the client using a GET request.

In later applications, there will be multiple clients, and I really want that clients perform their computation in parallel.

Comment: This is better answered by following a tutorial for your preferred web framework (I assume Flask, since that's how you tagged the question).

Comment: I have no clue about data science, but isn't `dask` built for such kind of tasks? https://dask.org/